# 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'

Tags: facebook, open-graph-protocol

自分のサイトにOGPタグを付けてオブジェクトデバッガーでテストしました。
結果以下の様なエラーが出ます。一見、プレビューでは正しく動いているように見えますが・・・。

"Object at URL 'https://makeyourownemblem.herokuapp.com/' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '/assets/makeyourownemblem-6b8a416ab775207c550c1ed587fdfc250bca16ff190fef9bc8bb5b8f40630f1f.png' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'."

これは何が問題なのでしょうか？ご存知のかたご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`og:image:url`の値が URL としてパースできないと書かれていますね。
パスは URL と見なされないという事だと思います。ドメインなども含めて記述する必要がありそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
ドメインも含めた書き方にしたら直りました！